# Sync Nokia 7230 Mobile Calendar With Google Calendar

Tags: sync, calendar, mobile-phone, google-calendar

I would like to synchronize the calendar on my mobile phone, a Nokia 7230, with my Google Calendar.  Can anyone offer any tips?

I would consider a paid service for this, but only if it specifically supports my make and model of phone.

Comment: Questions about mobile phones are considered off-topic.  Please see the FAQ. (http://superuser.com/faq)

Comment: heavyd, you might want to re-read the FAQ yourself.  It states "except insofar as they interface with your computer".  Given that I am asking for help with software to integrate my phone's calendar with Google Calendar, I believe this question is valid.

Comment: smartphone questions regarding synchronizing the phone with a computer are allowed here.  if this question is about trying to sync via the phone's data connection, it will be closed.  could you please clarify how you're trying to sync the phone?

Comment: note that there are several smartphone-related StackExchange sites [in this list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites) that may be better able to help you; in particular, [PhoneHow](http://phonehow.com) welcomes questions on all phone models.

Comment: quack quixote, I would appreciate answers using either a PC sync or a sync via the data connection.